# Debugging Gmail Contextual Gadgets?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, gwt, gmail

How would I go about doing this? Its becoming a real pain to deploy and not seeing anything pop up because of the cache. I have also try adding the tag at the end of the url where its suppose to clear the cache and it still doesn't help.

Would coding under Google Web Toolkit be a better choice in creating an app? Im pretty experienced in java so thats why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google actually provides a place where they talk about normal gadget debugging which works for the contextual gadgets:

http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/tools.html